# Hot to use certificate ticket in HTTP request

Tags: c#, http

I implement automatic file downloading as a windows service from the site via `HTTP`. To access the file, you must log in using the certificate and the digital signature key. In the browser in the developer tools (`F12`), I see that it sends a certain authorization to Post reuest `ticket`.

> {"ticket","7965FE11DCECA20296D734740CF3338D4A81D87203A47DFFACF311E15066581AED6F81DC8457A2EDD22BDCDFE539CBD766E7FC060E3B980FAF8F68BDE0986F1620E27C190F661E580729DB8155E91304F834408E75DA7CC1A71F796D99F2E28451353A245C1AD051C7BE5AE74DDED53022517289FFD8CD51739CEC4F04EF330A"
>   }

The ticket is new every time during authorization. This again, I see from the developer tools (`F12` in the browser)

If I substitute it into my program in `HttpClient`, then everything works fine. But after the reboot, the request with this ticket no longer passes.
**How is this ticket formed?** I would like to automatically generate this ticket and substitute it into the request. Now I prescribe hard. I have the digital signature key myself.

I'm trying to go to the site (https://br.so-ups.ru-00-0044/webapi/public/ssl/LoginByCert.aspx)
then a window appears with a certificate selection. I select the certificate I need and returns
in response headers
`Location https://br.so-ups.ru/Signin?redirect=#A807FED2F62B8EF4FE61371EF4F52F2603E1ADC375629473601F132B08835321173C49096CECC161A95B5F9F55DBD7F1665750444C02246CFB3C49A970409608799CF4950159BA86FDF77E8C11C4185B3A7F40C72AA0B522851BE07F41FD4A238983F4768E550F42C528F6B6F2F1E76D2A431B071F5B00496668F37979AF4761` 
This is apparently the network token from the server. But I can’t bind the certificate
 My code

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 certificateCh = null;
//Find user certificate
foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
 {
   if (certificate.Subject.Contains("Чич"))
    {
      certificateCh = certificate;
    }
  }

  var _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  _clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificateCh);
  _client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler);
  var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
  var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

But i get error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса. ---> System.Net.WebException: Базовое соединение закрыто: Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче. ---> System.IO.IOException: Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений 
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
```

Do I need to somehow connect root certificates?

sorry for my eanglish

Comment: There is no general rule how a tickt is built (it does not look like anything standardized I know). It may be retrieved from the server in a previous request, calculated by JavaScript code or a combination of both.

Comment: @Robert supplemented the question